# Passing Array into FlatList React Native (Not Rendering)

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

So I have this array, as shown below:

```
const categoryData=[
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "cat1",
            icon: icons.one
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "cat2",
            icon: icons.two
        },
]
```

I'm trying to store it in a useState const called categories, and then display categories in the data parameter within a FlatList:

`const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState(categoryData)`

```
<FlatList
    data={categories}
    keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    numColumns={4}
    contentContainerStyle={{ padding: SIZES.padding }}
/>
```

However, nothing renders when within the FlatList (important to note, the FlatList loads when a Modal is triggered, and the FlatList does render the items properly when `data={categoryData}` instead of just categories).

Thanks for the assistance.

EDIT: Here is an Expo link to depict the issue (https://snack.expo.dev/HsffYfsrc)

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you've shared. Perhaps the issue is caused by something else. Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what all the code is doing? If possible could you try creating a *running* [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Alright, I've linked the Expo example for you, its a very rough imitation of what I actually have, just reduced the amount of View components and etc, but it still produces the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code example you've used/referenced `categoryData` ***prior*** to it having been declared.

```
const App = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState(categoryData); // <-- used, undefined
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const categoryData = [ // <-- declared here
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'cat1',
      icon: 'test'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'cat2',
      icon: 'test'
    },
  ];

  function renderList() {
    ...
  }

  return <SafeAreaView>{renderList()}</SafeAreaView>;
}
```

I don't see any internal dependencies (*to the component*) to require that `categoryData` be declared within the component. I suggest declaring it ***outside*** the component so it's declared prior to the component and in scope.

```
const categoryData = [ // <-- declared
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'cat1',
    icon: 'test',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'cat2',
    icon: 'test',
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState(categoryData); // <-- defined
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

  function renderList() {
    ...
  }

  return <SafeAreaView>{renderList()}</SafeAreaView>;
};
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/d9afeb)

If `categoryData` is not known at compile time and is *actually* fetched later then provide valid initial state and load/update the `category` state in an `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([]); // <-- valid initial state
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    ... fetch/loading logic
    setModalVisible(data); // <-- update state with fetched/loaded data
  }, []);

  function renderList() {
    ...
  }

  return <SafeAreaView>{renderList()}</SafeAreaView>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say it works when Modal is triggered, then the issue might be that your data is not ready on load.
I suggest you try:

```
{categories && <FlatList
data={categories}
keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
renderItem={renderItem}
numColumns={4}
contentContainerStyle={{ padding: SIZES.padding }}/>}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to load the categories still, I've added an Expo link which is a rough example of what is occurring if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: I found the issue and I fixed it.
The issue was that you called **useState** with  array  **categoryData** but you declared **categoryData** later. The second issue was that your FlatList was inside modal and it appears only when you press to open Modal...